# Microsoft Adaptive Card "lang" attribute not working

Tags: json, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I am currently developing a chatbot, using Bot Framework and Adaptive Cards.

One of the dialogs is regarding weather information, and for so, I am presenting to the user the following adaptive card:

[Adaptive Card presented by chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjGcm.png)

As you can see the DATE and TIME of the card are presented in Portuguese language/format (based on the target device), although I want it to be always in English language/format.

I've tried to add the `lang` attribute to my `currentWeatherCard.json`, but with no success. I've also tried to change the `version` to `1.0`, `1.1` and `1.2`, but the problem remains. Changing the `Locale` of the Bot Framework Emulator does not have any effect on this, rather than changing the chat UI language.

Also, using the https://adaptivecards.io/designer and the **same `currentWeatherCard.json` data**, sometimes it does put the DATE and TIME in English, sometimes it does not.

What am I missing here?

```
//currentWeatherCard.json

{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"lang": "en",
"speak": "The current weather for ${name} is ${formatNumber(temp, 1)} degrees",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "${name}, ${country}",
        "size": "Large",
        "isSubtle": true,
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "{{DATE(${formatEpoch(dt, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}, SHORT)}}, {{TIME(${formatEpoch(dt, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')})}}",
        "spacing": "None",
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Image",
                        "url": "${icon}",
                        "size": "Small",
                        "altText": "${description}"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "auto",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "${formatNumber(temp, 1)}",
                        "size": "ExtraLarge",
                        "spacing": "None",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "°C",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Hi ${formatNumber(maxTemp, 1)} ºC",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Lo ${formatNumber(minTemp, 1)} ºC",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                        "spacing": "None",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}